# Sharing data betweeen Multiple Databases

Tags: api, multisite

We have a main organisation with civi multi-site build but finding it a little complex in terms of granting permissions for various sub departments. Thee are also clashes over mailings and issues with GDPR over accessing data.

Is it possible/feasable to have a main civi build and then import data from other 'seperate' civi builds through the API...?

That way each sub department can have their own database and (Drupal) website and information for 'all' the departments will also be stored on the main database. The only issue I see is the contact ID and my thought would be that this is listed as the 'external ID' on the sub (departmnent) builds.

Any thoughts on this or any suggested alternatives.

Many thanbks Robbie

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is any existing solution for this.

Though it should be possible by building an extension on your main site and pushing the data to the child sites everytime an entity is created/updated.

For eg, Create separate groups for each child sites, eg ChildA, ChildB and ChildC.

while creating a contact if Group A is selected, this contact will be pushed to the first child site.

We have done similar implementation for one of our client but it needs some pre-requisite information to be stored in the ext files, eg site key, API key, etc.

If interested to check our ext, get in touch at `jitendra@fuzion.co.nz`.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response...this is as expected, will chat to the team to see how they wish to proceed.